# Why does "in" work for keys but not for strings?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, iterable-unpacking

I came across a very weird thing with strings and dictionaries in Python today. Can someone explain to me why the print statement works in the first for loop but fails in the second for loop?

```
test = 'ab'
test_dict = {}
test_dict[test] = 1

for x, y in test_dict:
    print('%s %s' % (x,y))

for x,y in test:
    print('%s %s' % (x,y))
```

Comment: What is the full traceback?

Comment: The first print statement prints out:  "a b"  The second print statement is an error, as expected.

Comment: What do you think the y should print in the string case?

Comment: `test` is a string variable not a dictionary

Comment: It shouldn't and I never said it should. I just don't know why the first one prints anything at all.

Comment: "test is a string variable not a dictionary" So what? Why does the first one print out "a b" then? It is not printing out the key followed by the value. It is printing out the key split into 2 characters.

Comment: "@J.Mcclane Because you iterate of a dict with a key,value tuple. Which gets unpacked to the two loop variables." Not true, x and y are not (key,value) pairs. If this were the case, then y == 1. But y == b.

Comment: A dictonary is a collection of key-value pairs. `x,y` in this case is holding the key in `x` and the value in `y`

Comment: "A dictonary is a collection of key-value pairs. x,y in this case is holding the key in x and the value in y" Not true, see previous comment.

Comment: Iterating over the dictionary keys gives you a string of length two. Iterating over the string gives you a string of length one. Why *would* they be the same?

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code.

Answer (score 7):

**Both loops are broken.** The first one only *happens* to work due to the very specific coincidence that `test` is exactly two characters long, and so can be unpacked into two variables `x` and `y`.

To iterate over a dict's keys and values, write:

```
for k,v in d.items():
    ...
```

If you just want the keys you can do:

```
for k in d:
    ...
```

---

In detail, when you loop over a dict it iterates over the keys.

```
for x,y in test_dict
```

The dict has exactly one key, `"ab"`. So on the first and only iteration, it assigns that string to `x` and `y` as if you'd written:

```
x,y = "ab"
```

As it happens, this is a valid unpacking. Two variables on the left, a two-item container on the right. `x` becomes `"a"` and `y` becomes `"b"`.

If `test` were longer or shorter the first loop would also crash with either "need more than N values to unpack" or "too many values to unpack".

> Why is the string unpacked in 1 scenario but not unpacked in the other?

The second loop iterates over the string `"ab"` directly. When you iterate over a string it breaks the string into single-character strings. The first iteration is `"a"` and the second is `"b"`. On that first iteration, it tries to do:

```
x,y = "a"
```

This assignment fails with "need more than 1 value to unpack" because there are two variables on the left and only one character on the right.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say "broken"; the first loop is fine if you know the keys are two-character strings. But it does rely on that pretty specific assumption.

Answer (score 5):

For the dictionary case, you are iterating dictionary keys. `for x, y in test_dict` means "for each key in `test_dict` take the key and unpack to variables `x` and `y`". Since the only key is `'ab'`, the string is unpacked to `x = 'a'` and `y = 'b'`. Of course, this works specifically because your only string key has length 2.

For the string case, you are iterating a string. `for x, y in test` will fail. You can't say "for each character in `test` unpack to multiple variables" because a single character is not iterable. Instead, you will meet:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Comment: Why is the *string* unpacked in 1 scenario but not unpacked in the other?

Comment: @J.Mcclane, Because in one you are iterating dictionary keys (and the only key is iterable), the other you are iterating a string (and the characters in the string are not iterable). I've updated to clarify further.

Comment: In the second case, you're trying to unpack a single-character string "a". (`for c in "ab"` takes "a" and then "b", neither of which can be unpacked into `x` and `y`)

Answer (score 1):

```
for x,y in test:
  print('%s %s' % (x,y))
```

since `test` is a list-like object (a string in python is list-like), iterating over it takes each character in turn. A character is not a list-like object of length 2, so trying to split it into `x` and `y` produces an error. 
If you had `test = ("ab", "bc")` then test would be a tuple containing pairs of characters, which could be split using the expression above. 
That's a very short answer, but I hope it clarifies what's going on.

The reason this works in the dict case is a little more complicated, but not very complicated. When you iterate over a dict in python, you actually iterate over its keys. This means that you have a list of one item, which is a string of length 2. As you saw above, a string of length 2 can be unpacked into its first and second characters, which is why the statement works.